# Hardware back button for view created using LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I implemented `onKeyDown` in the activity to close the activity.Then added a button to the layout and implemented `setOnClickListener`. I managed to display another layout for the button click using `LayoutInflater`.I implemented `setOnKeyListner` for the View created using this `Inflater` for the hardware back button for that view.

But when I click the hardware back button while displaying the second layout, things inside the `setOnKeyListner` does not execute. for example following shows '1' instead of '2'.Can some one show my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, null);

            addContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            initGUI(view); //initialize layout views 

            view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View dialog, int keyCode,  KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        Log.i("tag","2");       

                    }
                    return true;
                 }
           });      
        }
        });

}
//Hardware key pressing event
@Override
       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.i("tag","1");
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

> tag 1

Because your activity instance is comman.
On button click you only add content to this activity but at the time of back press the context or reference of activity is comman so that it always call overrided method of activity.

Only your content is add to this activity layout but main context for activity is single that way this happens.

Comment: One another way is that on back press its execute "1" only but you can check on back key event that if your view!= NULL than remove that view than and than you can remove that new added view.